# Selenium CSS selector (Works in Scrapy but not Selenium) Python

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I have tried probably every kind of selector and am unable to output this selector as text.
Id, css selector, xpath, all return no result, but when using the same reference in Scrapy shell the desired output is returned.

Any Idea why the Selenium selector does not work?

I am trying to return the text in masterBody_trSalesDate

発売予定日   ：   7月(2021/4/21予約開始)

> https://www.example.co.jp/10777687

```
    try:
    hatsubai = driver.find_element_by_id('#masterBody_trSalesDate').text
```

I have honestly tried every possible combination elements and selectors I can think of with no luck, but as mentioned Scrapy shell DOES return the correct data so I am not sure what is going wrong.

Is there any way to test Selenium selectors like scrapy shell without running the script?

Thank you if you have any advice.

[image shows working in scrapy shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdJ7G.png)

Comment: first of all: masterBody_lblReservation doesn't exist on the web page you gave to us, 2nd: in scrapy you are using : masterBody_trSalesDate and not masterBody_lblReservation

Comment: I apologize, I have posted the wrong selector after trying so many different variations, I have edited the first post to correct the code

Comment: please consider checking this link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: if you use `by_id` then you don't need char `#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `by_id` or `by_xpath` then you don't need char `#`

```
hatsubai = driver.find_element_by_id('masterBody_trSalesDate').text
```

That's all.

---

Minimal working code which works for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
             
url = 'https://www.1999.co.jp/10777687'

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

hatsubai = driver.find_element_by_id('masterBody_trSalesDate').text   
print(hatsubai)

hatsubai = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="masterBody_trSalesDate"]').text
print(hatsubai)

hatsubai = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#masterBody_trSalesDate').text    
print(hatsubai)
```

---

**BTW:**

The same is with `by_class_name` - it needs only name without dot `.`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, it seems there is a bug in the script that is causing the selector to not be output correctly. I should have checked the very basics in an isolated test like this before asking. a lesson in debugging learnt I guess.

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css selector for this one:

```
hatsubai = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#masterBody_trSalesDate').text
print(hatsubai)
```

**Output:**

```
発売予定日 ： 7月(2021/4/21予約開始)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, it seems there is a bug in the script that is causing the selector to not be output correctly. even though I had tested this selector before.

Thank you for the help